# How do I interpolate a text file of 3D coordinates (X,Y,Z) onto a regular grid?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a 3D surface in a text file which I need to plot on a regular X/Y grid. However, the values for X and Y are not regularly spaced and are not necessarily in ascending order. I need to regularly space the X and Y coordinates and interpolate the value in the Z column. The Z column does not need to be sub-sampled.

Hear is an example of the file.
The columns are X, Y and Value (or Z):

```
50459.83        170405.62       0.01
50439.13        170384.92       0.03
50459.83        170384.92       0.04
50480.53        170384.92       0.01
50459.83        170364.22       0.13
50480.53        170364.22       0.14
50397.72        170343.51       0.27
50418.42        170343.51       0.33
50480.53        170343.51       0.32
50501.23        170343.51       0.36
50563.34        170343.51       0.29
```

I would like an output like:

```
50460        170400       0.01
50440        170380       0.03
50460        170380       0.04
50480        170380       0.01
50460        170360       0.13
```

I.e. have X and Y sampled on a 20x20 grid, and have the Z column interpolated to those grid points (which I have not done in the example output).

The file is very large, tens of millions of lines.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT from your sample input and output, you want to round the first field to the nearest 10, round down the second field down to the nearest 10, and leave the third field alone.

```
awk '{printf "%5.0f\t%6.0f\t%.2f\n", int($1/10+0.5)*10, int($2/10)*10, $3}' file
```

Output:

```
50460   170400  0.01
50440   170380  0.03
50460   170380  0.04
50480   170380  0.01
50460   170360  0.13
50480   170360  0.14
50400   170340  0.27
50420   170340  0.33
50480   170340  0.32
50500   170340  0.36
50560   170340  0.29
```